# SyntaxError: unexpected ':' in index.android.bundle when running react-native run-android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to test react-native code on my android device. Each time I run the `react-native run-android` on the terminal, it detects the android device and auto launch the app, but I get a modal box with the error message which reads:

```
syntaxError, unexpected token ':', parseError in index.android.bundle.
```

Comment: You will need to include source code to help identify the problem. Without being able to view your source, all that anyone can say is that you have a colon somewhere in your code that shouldn't be there.

Comment: i solved it, the version of node am using was 4.x and upgraded to node 6.x. everything seems to work fine